# Delay initializaton for JQuery drag and drop plugins

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Is it possible to delay the jQuery UI drag and drop plugins from being initialized until a movement or click is made?  Not sure if this is possible.  I have a ton of cells using the drag and drop, like an Excel grid, and performance isnt great.

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net / http://plnkr.co/edit/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went this route and it seems to work.

```
$.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
    this.one("mouseover", function () {
        if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either [delay](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-delay) or [distance](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-distance).

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ delay: 300 });

$( ".selector" ).draggable({ distance: 10 });
```

From the API documentation:

> **Delay**
>   Time in milliseconds after mousedown until dragging should start. This
>   option can be used to prevent unwanted drags when clicking on an
>   element.
>
> **Distance**
>   Distance in pixels after mousedown the mouse must move before dragging should start. This option can be used to prevent
>   unwanted drags when clicking on an element.

---

Update:

To keep a more standard functionality and only initialize draggable when needed, try using a hover function like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/vW8ny/3/)**

```
$('div').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selector');
    $(".selector").draggable({
        //options
    });
},

function () {
    $('div').removeClass('selector');
});
```

Comment: This would still initialize the element.  I want to try to initialize it maybe a button click and hold, and init drops when that element hovers over it, but not sure that is possible.  I dont want to initialize a 1000 cell grid at once if I dont have too.

Comment: You still have the click and then reclick to drag.  I want it to work exactly like before.

Comment: @MikeFlynn have you tried a more basic hover function? see update